# How to change certain style in css class without creating new css class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As title, how to change certain style in css class?

For example,

html (`direction` may be `rtl`. We don't know)

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.first {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html dir="ltr">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="first">1</div>
      <div class="second">2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If `dir="rtl"`, I want to set `background-color: cyan` in `.first`. How to do that with javascript?

I have found 2 solutions.

One is using `getElementsByClassName` and `style.backgroundColor = "cyan"`. It will create inline style to overwrite `.first`.

The other one is creating a new css class (e.g. `.rtlFirst`) to replace old one.

Can we just change `background-color: red` in `.first` to `background-color: cyan` without creating new class or inline style?

**Edit: Clarify my question**

If we use dev tools, we can see `style = "..."` in html in first solution (inline style).

If we don't want the inline style appears in html, I have found 2 solutions.

1. Append a new class to overwrite the property in `.first`
2. Replace `.first` with `rtlFirst` (`getElementsByClassName("first")` and use `classList.replace`)

Can we just replace `background-color` in `.first`?

Comment: No, because those are your options. Either set the style, inline, with js or however you want, OR overwrite the .first styleclass with new properties, OR write a new class and change it..

Comment: Clarify my question a little bit. If I use dev tools, inline style will appear in html. If I don't want it appears in html, can we do that?

Comment: Then both answers below are correct, i would opt for the css class with html[dir="rtl"] .first {..}, it's cleaner and no js needed

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use a CSS attribute selector specifying that whenever the text must be displayed, more styles should be aplyed.

```
html[dir="rtl"] .first {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

These styles will only be aplied if the direction is rtl, and they will overwrite the styles you had specified before.

Answer (score 1):

By using html[dir="rtl"] you can add css to the given class.

or you can also use the given js code to add the background color when needed

Solution :

```js
if(document.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].dir=="ltr")
{
document.getElementsByClassName("first")[0].style.backgroundColor="cyan";
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.first {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html dir="ltr">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first">1</div>
    <div class="second">2</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But we have used the existing class named first right ? @Rmaxx

Comment: Well now its edited and inline through js, but indeed still correct. My point is you will always need to overwrite either inline or via a class. The original question is faulty or it cannot be done ,"without inline style or a new class"